# Capturing ctrl+z key combination in javascript

Tags: javascript, combinations, ctrl

I am trying to capture <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> key combination in javascript with this code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
        function KeyPress(e) {
            var evtobj = window.event? event : e


            //test1 if (evtobj.ctrlKey) alert("Ctrl");
            //test2 if (evtobj.keyCode == 122) alert("z");
            //test 1 & 2
            if (evtobj.keyCode == 122 && evtobj.ctrlKey) alert("Ctrl+z");
        }

        document.onkeypress = KeyPress;
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Commented line "test1" generates the alert if I hold down the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key and press any other key.

Commented line "test2" generates the alert if I press the <kbd>z</kbd> key.

Put them together as per the line after "test 1 & 2", and holding down the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key then pressing the <kbd>z</kbd> key does not generate the alert as expected.

What is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

1. Use `onkeydown` (or `onkeyup`),  not `onkeypress`
2. Use `keyCode` 90, not 122

```
function KeyPress(e) {
      var evtobj = window.event? event : e
      if (evtobj.keyCode == 90 && evtobj.ctrlKey) alert("Ctrl+z");
}

document.onkeydown = KeyPress;
```

Online demo: http://jsfiddle.net/29sVC/

To clarify, **keycodes are not the same as character codes.**

Character codes are for text (they differ depending on the encoding, but in a lot of cases 0-127 remain ASCII codes). Key codes map to keys on a keyboard. For example, in unicode character 0x22909 means 好. There aren't many keyboards (if any) who actually have a key for this.

The OS takes care of transforming keystrokes to character codes using the input methods that the user configured. The results are sent to the keypress event. (Whereas keydown and keyup respond to the user pressing buttons, not typing text.)

Comment: Thanks, that works.

Why doesn't onkeypress and keyCode 122 work?

Comment: How to preventDefault() instead of alert in your solution please? I m testing for Ctrl+ t.

Comment: @SJnawali: I'm not sure it's possible for `ctrl+t`

Comment: _why does  keyCode 122 doesn't work?_ well, `122` is for **F11** key :)

Comment: @PaulJohnston Because a **key** code isn't the same as a **character** code. Character codes are for text (they differ depending on the encoding, but in a lot of cases 0-127 remain ASCII codes). Key codes map to keys on a keyboard. For example, in unicode character 0x22909 means 好. There aren't many keyboards (if any) who actually have a key for this. The OS takes care of transforming keystrokes to character codes using the input methods that the user configured. The results are sent to the `keypress` event. (Whereas `keydown` and `keyup` respond to the user pressing buttons, not typing text.)

Comment: @PaulJohnston I believe you have to use `keydown` because all the other events are too late. By that I mean the browser intercepts the command and performs the native undo, whereas on keydown, the browser hasn't yet taken note of the event

Comment: @casperOne Actually you are wrong... please check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15310690. acc to this the keydown gets triggered for all keys but on the other hand keypress triggers only when a character is pressed.

Comment: dont forget about event.metaKey

Comment: please note **window.event** is deprecated.

Answer (score 125):

For future folks who stumble upon this question, here’s a better method to get the job done:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  if (event.ctrlKey && event.key === 'z') {
    alert('Undo!');
  }
});
```

Using [`event.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) greatly simplifies the code, removing hardcoded constants. It has support for IE 9+.

Additionally, using [`document.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) means you won’t clobber other listeners to the same event.

Finally, there is no reason to use [`window.event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event). It’s actively discouraged and can result in fragile code.

Comment: Furthermore, I would add that `KeyboardEvent.keyCode` is now deprecated since a couple years ago.  The best way to capture all browsers is checking `e.key` first and then fallback to `e.keyCode`.  Or [you can use this polyfill](https://github.com/cvan/keyboardevent-key-polyfill/)

Comment: do not forget about event.metaKey

Answer (score 10):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> is also possible...just use the keycode as 84 like

```
if (evtobj.ctrlKey && evtobj.keyCode == 84) 
 alert("Ctrl+t");
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
  if( e.which === 89 && e.ctrlKey ){
     alert('control + y'); 
  }
  else if( e.which === 90 && e.ctrlKey ){
     alert('control + z'); 
  }          
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ba54W/258/)

Answer (score 4):

```
document.onkeydown = function (e) {
    var special = e.ctrlKey || e.shiftKey;
    var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode;
  console.log(key.length);
  if (special && key == 38 || special && key == 40 ) { 
    // enter key do nothing
    e.preventDefault();
  }        
}
```

here is a way to block two keys, either shift+ or Ctrl+ key combinations.

&& helps with the key combinations, without the combinations, it blocks all ctrl or shift keys.

Answer (score 3):

90 is the <kbd>Z</kbd> key and this will do the necessary capture...

```
function KeyPress(e){
     // Ensure event is not null
     e = e || window.event;

     if ((e.which == 90 || e.keyCode == 90) && e.ctrlKey) {
         // Ctrl + Z
         // Do Something
     }
}
```

Depending on your requirements you may wish to add a `e.preventDefault();` within your if statement to exclusively perform your custom functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The `KeyboardEvent.keyCode` is deprecated ([link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode)) think about using `KeyboardEvent.key` instead ([link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key)).

So, the solution would be something like this.

```
if (e.key === "z" && e.ctrlKey) {
   alert('ctrl+z');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[image]

You can actually see it all in the KeyboardEvent when you use keydown event

Answer (score -1):

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
if ((event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) &&event.shiftKey && event.key === 'z') {
  console.log('Redo!');
}else if ((event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) && event.key === 'z') {
  console.log('Undo!');
}else if ((event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) && event.key === 'c') {
  console.log('Copy!');
}else if ((event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) && event.key === 'v') {
  console.log('Paste!');
}else if ((event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) && event.key === 'x') {
  console.log('Cropp!');
}
```

});

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

Use this code for <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. keycode for <kbd>Z</kbd> in keydown is 90 and the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> is ctrlKey. check this keycode in your console area

```
 $(document).on("keydown", function(e) {
       console.log(e.keyCode, e.ctrlKey);
       /*ctrl+z*/
       if (e.keyCode === 90 && e.ctrlKey) { // this is confirmed with MacBook pro Monterey on 1, Aug 2022
       {
          //your code here
       }
    });
```

Comment: Can someone explain why this response has been down voted so much? It is correct. Or is it because it is a windows thing?

Comment: @ColinWiseman It doesn't work for me on Windows. Also, `keypress` is deprecated.

Comment: if the keypress is deprecated, please use the keydown for getting the code. I used 26 as the keycode for ctrl+z. please confirm this with console.log. Thanks

Comment: deprecations and changes frequently happen in javascript. So please read the docs if the post is too old. Then only you can decide the keycode for your code.

Comment: deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keypress_event