# How can I interact with browser control+z/control+y for undo/redo?

Tags: javascript

I'm creating my own editor, and I'm finally tackling the undo/redo issue that I've been dodging for weeks.

I have created the base framework for storing and traversing the history of custom actions, but I cannot seem to find good information on how to interact with the *browsers* history in a `contentEditable` area.

Looking at https://github.com/jzaefferer/undo/blob/master/undo.js, I still do not see how this is done.

I can undo/redo my *custom* actions, but I'm oblivious to how I can tap into the browsers default history.

*Will I have to add **all** of the original functionality if I am to override the default **control + ( z | y )**?*

**Update:** Where can I find more information about how the browser handles these undo/redo actions?

Comment: You mean the pages they have visited?

Comment: You don't **have** to, just make sure you're fine with the usability issue you'll create if you cut out part of the default functionality.

Comment: This has nothing to do with page history.. HTML5 contentEditable history.. text being typed, `execCommand`, etc. @blgt Is there no way to have the 2 simply co-exist?? If I could find a resource on how it works, I would have a much better idea of what can and cannot be done.

Comment: Most cases i've seen simply used the browser's built-in undo/redo functionality. Why do you need special functionality to handle your custom actions?

Comment: @KevinB There are things that are beyond the browsers default ability - toggling classes, creation of new elements, etc. They do not undo/redo (even register) with the normal stack.

Comment: Then the answer is probably **Yes**

Comment: 7 years... no answers (btw, problem is actual)

Answer (score 4):

Check out the source of the contenteditable [demo](https://github.com/jzaefferer/undo/blob/master/demos/contenteditable.html) to figure out more about how he attached the library to the div.

```
$(function() {
    var stack = new Undo.Stack(),
        EditCommand = Undo.Command.extend({
            constructor: function(textarea, oldValue, newValue) {
                this.textarea = textarea;
                this.oldValue = oldValue;
                this.newValue = newValue;
            },
            execute: function() {
            },
            undo: function() {
                this.textarea.html(this.oldValue);
            },

            redo: function() {
                this.textarea.html(this.newValue);
            }
        });
    stack.changed = function() {
        stackUI();
    };

    var undo = $(".undo"),
        redo = $(".redo"),
        dirty = $(".dirty");
    function stackUI() {
        undo.attr("disabled", !stack.canUndo());
        redo.attr("disabled", !stack.canRedo());
        dirty.toggle(stack.dirty());
    }
    stackUI();

    $(document.body).delegate(".undo, .redo, .save", "click", function() {
        var what = $(this).attr("class");
        stack[what]();
        return false;
    });

    var text = $("#text"),
        startValue = text.html(),
        timer;
    $("#text").bind("keyup", function() {
        // a way too simple algorithm in place of single-character undo
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            var newValue = text.html();
            // ignore meta key presses
            if (newValue != startValue) {
                // this could try and make a diff instead of storing snapshots
                stack.execute(new EditCommand(text, startValue, newValue));
                startValue = newValue;
            }
        }, 250);
    });

    $(".bold").click(function() {
        document.execCommand("bold", false);
        var newValue = text.html(); 
        stack.execute(new EditCommand(text, startValue, newValue));
        startValue = newValue;
    });

            // This is where he attaches the observer for undo / redo.
            // For more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16006583/capturing-ctrlz-key-combination-in-javascript
    $(document).keydown(function(event) {
        if (!event.metaKey || event.keyCode != 90) {
            return;
        }
        event.preventDefault();
        if (event.shiftKey) {
            stack.canRedo() && stack.redo()
        } else {
            stack.canUndo() && stack.undo();
        }
    });
});
```

[Capturing ctrl+z key combination in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16006583/capturing-ctrlz-key-combination-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4):

Use this, but it works as it should only with `<div contentEditable="true">` boxes. In textarea it undoes and redoes all text at once, not word by word as in div.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function Undo() { document.execCommand("undo", false, null); }
function Redo() { document.execCommand("redo", false, null); }
</script>

<div contentEditable="true" style="background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.8); resize:none; width: 499px; height: 230px; border: 1px solid red;"></div>
<input type="button" onmouseup="Undo()" value="Undo" />
<input type="button" onmouseup="Redo()" value="Redo" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is anyway to directly access the contents of the undo buffer, but you can trigger an undo or redo using [document.execCommand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.execCommand). Simple example:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
  #box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: grey;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="box" contenteditable="true"></div>
  <button id="undo">Undo</button>
  <button id="redo">Redo</button>
<script>
  var box = document.getElementById('box');
  var undo = document.getElementById('undo');
  var redo = document.getElementById('redo');

  undo.addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
    document.execCommand('undo', false, null);
  });

  redo.addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
    document.execCommand('redo', false, null);
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Check it is out as a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S4JhM/).

Comment: That doesn't really help my situation. I'm aware I can do this for `execCommand` functions, but things such as text being typed are way outside of the range of this answer. The default undo/redo does much more than bold/unbold, etc.. I just need it to do even *more*, and co-exist with my custom actions. It looks like I'll have to "hack" the default capabilities and overwrite it completely..

Comment: I think you should clarify your question a bit. Your question seems to be about how to access the default undo/redo functionality even when overwriting the typical (ctrl-c/z) shortcuts. It would help if you explained what you want to accomplish. What is the _even more_ functionality that you need? I think this question has a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).