# Key sequence using event keys to load href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

***SOLVED VIA COMMENT charCode needed to be 3 which is ctrl+pause thanks  Jaromanda X***

So I have been through this site and can't seem to find what I am looking for. Currently I have the following for my JS. I am trying to make it work with ctrl+pause so it will load the TacomaSB.hta after pressing the key sequence ctrl+pause. If its already on the site please provide it but I couldn't seem to locate what I needed :L

```
  <script>
  function hrefKeyDown(evt)
 { 
var ev = ((window.event)?(window.event):(evt)); 
var ahref = document.getElementById('connect');
var charCode = ((window.event)?(window.event.keyCode):(((evt.which)?(evt.which):(evt.keyKode))));
if(charCode==19)
{ 
ahref.click();
} 
}
  </script>
```

Here is the body.

```
<body onkeydown="hrefKeyDown(event);return false;">
    <a href="/TacomaSB.hta" onclick="document.login_form.submit(); return false;" name="connect" id="connect" onkeydown = "hrefKeyDown(event);return false;"></a>
```

At the moment I have it working fine with pause but I can't figure out how to do both charCode 19(pause) and charCode 17(ctrl)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capturing ctrl+z key combination in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16006583/capturing-ctrlz-key-combination-in-javascript)

Comment: ctrl+pause actually results in ctrlKey being true, and a keycode of **3** - because keyboards are weird

Comment: OMG THANK YOU @JaromandaX that's all it was... Your the best

Comment: historically, break (which is what ctrl+pause is) was ctrl+c .. ctrl+c == ascii `03` - hence why (perhaps) ctrl+pause == ctrlKey:true + keyCode:3

Comment: Interesting well thank you my good sir!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Had to change the charCode to 3 was 19 solved via Jaromanda X
<script>

  function hrefKeyDown(evt)
 { 
var ev = ((window.event)?(window.event):(evt)); 
var ahref = document.getElementById('connect');
var charCode = ((window.event)?(window.event.keyCode):(((evt.which)?(evt.which):(evt.keyKode))));
if(charCode==3)
{ 
ahref.click();
} 
}
  </script>
```