# Ctrl-Z/Y makes the browser focus on a recently changed input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a canvas web application where I can an undo actions by pressing Ctrl+Z
The application has also got text input elements

When I hit Ctrl+Z, on some occasions, the browser automatically focuses on a recently changed input. Does anyone know how to prevent this?

I'm using Chrome.

Comment: To be clear, you want to still carry out the undo/redo operation but not change the focus? If so I don't believe this is possible. It's part of the OS behaviour that the edited field regains focus.

Comment: Mmm I was afraid of that. Thanks anyway

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capturing ctrl+z key combination in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16006583/capturing-ctrlz-key-combination-in-javascript)

Comment: You can intercept `document.onkeydown` and `return false` to disable the browser's control-z.  Likely browser dependent, but worked fine for me in Chrome.  Example fiddle (tweaked from the above duplicate): http://jsfiddle.net/btm8qkxL/

Answer (score 2):

In regards to Oak's answer, in my case I couldn't just `preventDefault()` every keydown because we need the key strokes so this worked for me:

```
 keyHandler = (e: KeyboardEvent) => {
   switch (e.key) {
    case e.ctrlKey && 'z': {
      e.preventDefault();
      break;
    }
}
```

It is strange how an `onBlur` doesn't stop this from happening but if a user manually clicks off the input then CTRL + Z automatically doesn't call the input...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, though interestingly on Windows only. Calling `preventDefault()` on the event solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I still needed to allowing Ctrl+Z (and Ctrl+Y) when the text inputs are focused:

Utilizing the same strategy as Martin's answer, we can get rid of the chrome behavior of refocusing a previously focused element when there is no focus (the body is focused).

```js
window.addEventListener("keydown", e => 
{
  if (e.target == document.body && e.ctrlKey && (e.key == "z" || e.key == "y"))
  {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Firefox doesn't seem to have this same behavior so it definitely doesn't seem to be an OS behavior.

Hopefully this is still relevant to you, or can be useful to others searching in the future!