# Userscript not capturing ctrlKey keydown event

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey, userscripts, keylogger, greasemonkey-4

The following userscript is not capturing the ctrlKey event.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name      CtrlKey alert
// @namespace CtrlKey alert
// @include   *
// @run-at    document-start
// ==/UserScript==

document.addEventListener(
  "keydown",
  function (zEvent) {
    if (zEvent.ctrlKey) {
      zEvent.preventDefault();
      alert("CtrlKey pressed!");
    }
  },
  true
);
```

An identical user script can capture any other key event, though:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name      Key A alert
// @namespace Key A alert
// @include   *
// @run-at      document-start
// ==/UserScript==

document.addEventListener(
  "keydown",
  function (zEvent) {
    if (zEvent.key === "a") {
      zEvent.preventDefault();
      alert("Key A pressed!");
    }
  },
  true
);
```

I have tried using `zEvent.stopPropagation`, `zEvent.stopImmediatePropagation`, and `zEvent.preventDefault` individually but they have had no effect (this is important because the ultimate goal is to override a default ctrl+letter command like `ctrl+f`).

I have tried substituting `document.addEventListener('keydown', function(zEvent)` with `document.onKeydown = function(zEvent)` with no results.

**Everything I've read indicates that `keydown` or `onKeydown` *should* capture ctrlKey, yet it doesn't. Is there something specific about ctrlKey I'm missing that's preventing javascript from capturing it?**

Running Firefox v105.0.1 on Windows 11

Comment: The `ctrlKey` is a modifier to a keypress.  Try hitting ctrl-A and you will see that `ctrlKey` is set, but you can't detect the ctrl key by itself in JavaScript AFAIK.

Example of what I mean: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16006607/2740650

Comment: The code that you linked, `if (event.ctrlKey && event.key === 'z')`, is the same as what I attempted in my question. In fact, my original goal WAS to capture the "ctrl + A" combination. I saw that it was NOT being captured, and I narrowed down the issue to `event.ctrlKey` not being captured.

Comment: Oh, not the way I interpreted it.  OK, then it would be simpler to add a log like `console.log(zEvent)` to the handler in the first line.  It should log something for every keystroke.  Please edit your question to post the output when you hit ctrl+A.  Also, try omitting the last parameter to `addEventListener` where you have specified `true`.